# gulp sass: merge folders with file inheritance

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

I have a folder structure like this (simplified):

```
|-project1
|--_file1.scss
|--_file2.scss
|--_file3.scss
|
|-project2
|--_file2.scss
|
|-css
|--project1.css
|--project2.css
```

I am looking for a way to compile the sass files with inheritance. The idea behind this is, that I have a base project (project1) and project 2 only contains those files that need to be changed.

So upon compilation gulp should render 2 css files:

1. project1.css
   This contains only the files from project1/scss/ folder
2. project2.css
   This one should contain file1 and file3 from project 1 and file2 from project 2.

Is this possible? What modules would be needed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work for you.  I note that you have all and only **partials** in your project folders, i.e. _file1.scss, _file2.scss, etc.  You will have to have at least one file that is not a partial that imports those partials for sass to work.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');

// const glob = require("glob");

const sources = ['project1', 'project2', 'project3'];
    //  could glob your sourceFolders with something like
    // const sources = glob.sync("project*");
const filterSources = Object.keys(sources);

function isUnique(file, index) {

  console.log(path.basename(file.path));  // file1.scss, file2.scss, etc.  all from project1

  baseName = path.basename(file.path);
  folder = sources[index];  // project

  //  does that basename exist in thecurrent  project (sources[index] )
  return !fs.existsSync(folder + path.sep + baseName);
}

gulp.task('default', function () {

      //  loop through all the project folders
  filterSources.forEach(function (project, index) {

    const f = filter(function (file) {
      return isUnique(file, index);
    });

    //  always using project1 files as basis
    const stream = gulp.src('./project1/*.scss')

      //  filter out from the source stream (project1 files) any files that appear in the current project directory
      .pipe(f)

      //  add all files from the current project directory, i.e., project2, project3, etc.
      .pipe(addsrc.append('./' + sources[index] + '/*.scss'))

      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))

      //  give the concat the filename of the current project
      .pipe(concat(sources[index] + '.css'))

      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

    return stream;
  });
```

This works for any number of project folders, just make sure that your non-partial scss file that imports the others is not one that is filtered out.

But it looks like you don't really want any partials anyway since you want to **concat** all files in each project so remove those leading underscores from each file name.

Comment: Thank you. You definately pushed me into the right direction. Your are somewhat right concerning the partials. Since it is a magento project the system could take care about what to include and what not. Unfortunately I am trying to work on a foundation project and it seems impossible to NOT use partials. I wish I could do this inheritance stuff on the sass level (@import).